# Call to a member function record_count() on null codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Trying to set up some pagination from a database that has a list of members in it. I had a query that returned the results but I could not incorporate it into the pagination example I found on the internet. Now i get a Call to a member function record_count() on null error when I try to load my memberlist. Below is the code.

**Model**

```
public function count_members()
{
    return $this->db->count_all("Users");
}

public function getMembers($limit, $start)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get("users");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        return $data;
    }
    return false;
    /*if ($id == null) {
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
    }else{
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', ['id' => $id]);
    }
    return $query->result();  */
}
```

**View**

```
<h1>Member Listing</h1>
<table border="1" align="center">
<thead>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email Address</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Last Login</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th>Write Up</th>
<thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($members as $_key => $_value): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?=$_value->first_name?></td>
    <td><?=$_value->last_name?></td>
    <td><?=$_value->email?></td>
    <td><?=$_value->status?></td>
    <td><?=$_value->last_login?></td>
    <td><a href="<?=site_url("admin/delete_member/{$_value->id}");?>">[X]</a></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php echo $links; ?></p>
</tbody>
</table>
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/home">Back to Dashboard</a>
```

**Controller**

```
public function view_members()
    {
        $this->load->model('Users_model');
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "admin/view_members";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->Users->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 20;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data["results"] = $this->Users->getMembers($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        //$this->data['members'] = $this->Users_model->getMembers();
        $this->load->view('admin/inc/admin_header');
        $this->load->view('admin/view_members', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('admin/inc/admin_footer');
    }
```

**Error Messages**
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Admin::$users

Filename: controllers/Admin.php

Line Number: 217

Fatal error: Call to a member function count_members() on null in G:\xampp\htdocs\highball061516\application\controllers\Admin.php on line 217
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function count_members() on null

Filename: controllers/Admin.php

Line Number: 217

Comment: Include the full error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code igniter pagnation, `$config["total_rows"]` parameter requires total number of records exists in database. In your code, it was getting this count form a function that doesn't exists in model. It should get it from `count_members` instead. Here is the updated controller code:

```
public function view_members()
{
    $this->load->model('Users_model');
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "admin/view_members";

    // Code modified here
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->Users_model->count_members();

    $config["per_page"] = 20;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->Users->getMembers($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    //$this->data['members'] = $this->Users_model->getMembers();
    $this->load->view('admin/inc/admin_header');
    $this->load->view('admin/view_members', $this->data);
    $this->load->view('admin/inc/admin_footer');
}
```

Comment: Try now. Reference to `count_members` was wrong earlier. Updated code...